# How to count total number of rows in jqgrid treegrid mode

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using `jqGrid in treegrid mode`, my problem is that i want to the total number of rows in the grid for some manipulations?
I've tried `records` and `reccount` but they seems to count only the rows return by the server against the request. My grid loads data on demand and when i delete all the children of a row both of above options return 0?

Any hints or ideas regarding this?

Comment: Can you look at the html structure and use that to create a selector that selects the elements you want, then get your count from that?

Comment: i'm currently using that but i just want to know if jqgrid contains some options ( a good practice) :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that your TreeGrid loads the data "on-demand" if the user click on the expand button of the tree node. In the case you have to send your custom request to the server who "knows" all nodes of the TreeGrid. jqGrid has no information about this.

If needed you can send **the total number of items** in Tree Grid (and not in the last response only) in the server response in `records` part of the JSON or XML response. I don't tested this, but it seems to me that in the case the `records` parameter of TreeGrid will be not overwritten and you can use it.